# can't access isolated text in XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774656/cant-access-text-bloc-using-xpath/37775723#37775723) related to this, but I did not think I would face another problem. Here is my sample XML file :

```
<section>
    Hello everyone, I'm
    <bold>Hackmania</bold>
    <bold>15</bold>
    <line/>
    I am looking for an
    <highlight>answer</highlight>
    <paragraph/>

    Here is an other
    <bold>paragraph</bold>
    <highlight>with the same tags</highlight>
    <paragraph/>
</section>
```

How could I put my isolated texts into a specific tag, let's say `<myText></myText>`? like this :

```
<section>
    <p>
        <myText>Hello everyone, I'm</myText>
        <bold>Hackmania</bold>
        <bold>15</bold>
        <line/>
        <myText>I am looking for an</myText>
        <highlight>answer</highlight>
    </p>
    <p>
        <myText>HHere is an other</myText>
        <bold>paragraph</bold>
        <highlight>with the same tags</highlight>
    </p>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the

```
    <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
        <p>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('grpById', generate-id())"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

in the referenced solution you can use

```
    <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('grpById', generate-id())"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

and then make sure you do

```
<xsl:template match="section/text()">
  <myText>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </myText>
</xsl:template>
```

plus the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to copy the rest unchanged.

So the whole stylesheet then is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="grpById" match="node()[not(self::paragraph)]" use="generate-id(following-sibling::paragraph[1])" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section/text()">
        <myText>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
        </myText>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/section">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
                <p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('grpById', generate-id())"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```